# Write specific JSON fields to file

Tags: json, go

I've just started studying Golang and don't understand how to write only specific JSON fields to an output file.

For example I have this struct:

```
type example struct {
        Ifindex  int    `json:"ifindex"`
        HostID   int    `json:"host_id"`
        Hostname string `json:"hostname"`
        Name     string `json:"name"`
}
```

My output file should be in the following format:

```
[{"Ifindex": int, "Hostname": string}, {...}]
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Golang ignore Json fields when marshalling not unmarshalling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47256201/golang-ignore-json-fields-when-marshalling-not-unmarshalling)

Answer (score 3):

If I understood correctly, you'd like to omit some of the fields when marshalling to JSON. Then use `json:"-"` as a field tag.

Answer (score 3):

Per the [`json.Marshal(...)` documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal):

> As a special case, if the field tag is "-", the field is always omitted.

So you just need to use the tag `"-"` for any public field that you do not want serialized, for example ([Go Playground](https://play.golang.com/p/yHYYozCkV5x)):

```
type Example struct {
  Ifindex  int    `json:"ifindex"`
  HostID   int    `json:"-"`
  Hostname string `json:"hostname"`
  Name     string `json:"-"`
}

func main() {
  eg := Example{Ifindex: 1, HostID: 2, Hostname: "foo", Name: "bar"}
  bs, err := json.Marshal(&eg)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }

  fmt.Println(string(bs))
  // {"ifindex":1,"hostname":"foo"}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I need!